# Dynamic width of Table as per column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-tables

I have one table which display data as from Dynamic Content, I want to make table **width 100%** when there is 6 cols. and table **width auto** if less the 5 cols.

I tried with CSS but, when there is only two cols, it expand two cols to full width while have table 100% width and looks awkward.

Is there any Javascript, jQuery script available to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery and ensuring you choose the first row in the table body in case the thead has a different layout.

```
function setTableWidth(tableId) {

    var $tbl = $('#'+tableId);
    var newWidth = $tbl.find('tbody>tr:eq(0)>td').length > 5 ? '100%' : 'auto';
    $tbl.width(newWidth)

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're loading the dynamic content, there might be an easier way, but this function should do what you need:

```
function setTableWidth(tableId) {
    myTable = document.getElementById('tableId');
    if (myTable.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length > 5)
        myTable.style.width = '100%';
    else
        myTable.style.width = 'auto';
 }
```

Note though, that it won't work if any of the cells in the first row have a colspan. It's simply counting the number of columns in the first row and setting the width based on that.

Comment: Thank you very much .. Let me try this.